# Why does json.loads() work on some strings?

Tags: python, json

I've a JSON string like the one shown in `json1`. I'm trying to parse this as a JSON but it doesnt seem to work. What is going wrong?

```
import json

string1 = "[]"
list1 = "['hi','bye']"
json1 = "{'genre': ['Action', 'Comedy']}"

print json.loads(string1)
print json.loads(list1)
print json.loads("{'genre': ['Action', 'Comedy']}")
```

It gives me the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 8, in <module>
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Comment: `list1` is not in json format

Comment: because they're not valid json...http://www.json.org/, JSON strings should be double quoted `print json.loads('{"genre": ["Action", "Comedy"]}')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

json expects double quoted strings, you have single-quoted strings. You can load your strings using `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
print(ast.literal_eval("{'genre': ['Action', 'Comedy']}"))
```

result:

```
{'genre': ['Action', 'Comedy']}
```

Comment: Oh great! Phew, such a small detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

JSON (unlike JavaScript or Python) [only allows double-quoted strings](http://json.org/).

```
>>> print json.loads('["hi","bye"]')
[u'hi', u'bye']

>>> print json.loads("['hi','bye']")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Because of this, and because Python tends to prefer *single*-quoted strings, the `repr()` of a Python object is almost always *invalid* JSON.  You must use `json.dumps()` instead.

```
>>> v = ["hi", "bye"]
>>> repr(v)
"['hi', 'bye']"
>>> json.dumps(v)
'["hi", "bye"]'
```